# Download GeoTIFF from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, download

I have remote GeoServer with published GeoTIFF's which have data security via login/password. Initial size GeoTIFF about 5-10Gb. Is there any way download raw GeoTIFF file from GeoServer (using Python script, web URL link ...)?

**Updated 26.02.2016**

Example WCS URL for download raster files:

```
var workspace = layer.params.LAYERS.split(':');
var downloadurl = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/" + workspace[0] + "/wcs?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&CoverageId=" + layer.params.LAYERS + "&format=image/tiff"
window.open(downloadurl);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with the OGC standard [WCS](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wcs/index.html). Think that WCS is something like WFS but for raster.

But, as [@simogeo explains](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181560/download-geotiff-from-geoserver/181561?noredirect=1#comment273851_181561)

> If your goal is to download plain geotif files with no processing
>   (crop, scale, reproject) I would suggest to go for a specific WPS
>   process (that you have to create) that simple give access to the
>   original file. I mean, using WCS to extract the original file is a bit
>   of an overkill, if you need to exchange the dump of the database with
>   N persons you would do the dump one and then use that rather than
>   doing a select all and writing to an output file N times, right?
>
> As an alternative you may want to expose your data via FTP or HTTP and put those links in the layer metadata so people can reach the file
>   directly.

Comment: If your goal is to download plain geotif files with no processing (crop, scale, reproject) I would suggest to go for a specific WPS process (that you have to create) that simple give access to the original file.

I mean, using WCS to extract the original file is a bit of an overkill, if you  need to exchange the dump of the database with N persons you would do the dump one and then use that rather than doing a select all and writing to an output file N times, right?

Comment: As an alternative you may want to expose your data via FTP or HTTP and put those links in the layer metadata so people can reach the file directly.

Comment: Your comment is very accurate @simogeo i edit my answer to include it.

Comment: Thanks @Francisco Puga and @simogeo! I have another problem - when I use WCS service for download GeoTIFF with large size (about 7Gb) I receive exception: "The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: localhost:8080/geoserver/imagespace/wcs? Read Timeout The system returned: [No Error] A Timeout occurred while waiting to read data from the network. The network or server may be down or congested. Please retry your request." Is it possible to increase the value of "Timeout" for download files with large size? Example used WCS URL I added in question post. Thanks!

Comment: that is exactly what I said.

A synchronous service like WCS is no good for downloading large data. Sooner or later the underlying HTTP request will timeout.